# What should I replace on a double-flush toilet to stop internal leaking?

Tags: toilet

My double-flush toilet will add water at random times, so I guess it's leaking down the water level causing this.  Not familiar with the dual flush unit. What should I replace?

Comment: What make/model of toilet?

Comment: WELL NOT SURE BUT I GUESS I NEED TO KOW THAT FOR MY QUESTION .JUST ASSUMED ALL DOUBLE FLUSH TANKS UNITS WERE CREATED EQUAL FOR LEAK DOWN PROBLEMS

Comment: The *general* answers are likely to be the same. But there may be specific problems with particular makes/models, and/or someone may have experience with a particular model to tell you *exactly* what to look for.

Comment: WELL WHEN I GO HOME FOR LUNCH  I WILL GET WHAT I CAN FIND ON IT

Comment: All capitol letters is the grammatical equivalent of yelling while speaking, Please do not yell at us.

Comment: How high is the water? Is it up to the very top of the overflow drain, or not?